# Trying to auto-calculate in the input box but the input isn't showing

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an assignment where I need to place in JavaScript into my HTML. I needed to make an auto-calculate feature that would display the answer on a grey input box which is read only. However, it just doesn't show, I needed to know if it is a problem with the coding.

Here's my JavaScript code:

```
function calculate_Total() {
    document.querySelector('#total_1').value = parseFloat(price_1.value) * parseFloat(qty1.value);
}

const price_1 = document.querySelector('#price_1');
const qty_1 = document.querySelector('#qty_1');

price_1.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => calculate_Total());
qty_1.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => calculate_Total());
```

And here's the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Order a book!</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/book-order.css">
    <script src="JS/book-order.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>No.</th>
                    <th>Book Title</th>
                    <th>Author</th>
                    <th>Category</label></th>
                    <th>Unit Price</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th>
                    <th>Total</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01"/></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_1" min="0" value="0" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" onchange="calculate_Total()" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onchange="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_1" min="0" value="0" onchange="calculate_Total()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly onchange="calculate_Total()"/></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onchange="calc()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_1" min="0" value="0" onchange="calc()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>4</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onchange="calc()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_1" min="0" value="0" onchange="calc()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>5</td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="category">
                            <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
                                <option value="bsn">Business</option>
                                <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
                                <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
                                <option value="tech">Technology</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="price" id="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" onchange="calc()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="qty" id="qty_1" min="0" value="0" onchange="calc()" /></td>
                    <td><input type="number" name="total" id="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <td colspan="5">
                    <div style="text-align: right">
                        <button onclick="calculate();">Calculate Grand Total Price</button>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td colspan="2">
                    <div style="text-align: right;">
                        <input type="number" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="0.00" readonly>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </form>
<script src="book-order.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Edit: I've changed the IDs for a bit, so this is to be ignored at the moment, but still when I type, it doesn't show according to this image.
[The output in the grey input box is not showing.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A551f.png)

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique, you have multiple elements with the same `id`.

Comment: Also, you've used `qty1` instead of `qty_1`

Answer (score 0):

As it has been said already, an element's id should be unique in a file. I'm sure there are better ways to achieve what you are trying to do. To make your code work without changing much of the code, all we need to do is to change element id's into classes and then attach event handlers to each of them.

```js
function calculate_Total(elementIndex) {
  document.querySelectorAll('.total_1')[elementIndex].value = parseFloat(price_1[elementIndex].value) * parseFloat(qty_1[elementIndex].value);
}

const price_1 = document.querySelectorAll('.price_1');
const qty_1 = document.querySelectorAll('.qty_1');

price_1.forEach((element, key) => {
  element.addEventListener("keyup", e => calculate_Total(key));
});


qty_1.forEach((element, key) => {
  element.addEventListener("keyup", e => calculate_Total(key));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Order a book!</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/book-order.css">
</head>

<body>
  <form>
    <h1>Book Ordering System</h1>
    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>No.</th>
          <th>Book Title</th>
          <th>Author</th>
          <th>Category</label>
          </th>
          <th>Unit Price</th>
          <th>Quantity</th>
          <th>Total</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td>1</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
          <td>
            <select id="category">
              <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
              <option value="bsn">Business</option>
              <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
              <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
              <option value="tech">Technology</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="qty" class="qty_1" min="0" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="total" class="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>2</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
          <td>
            <select id="category">
              <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
              <option value="bsn">Business</option>
              <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
              <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
              <option value="tech">Technology</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="qty" class="qty_1" min="0" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="total" class="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>3</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
          <td>
            <select id="category">
              <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
              <option value="bsn">Business</option>
              <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
              <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
              <option value="tech">Technology</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="qty" class="qty_1" min="0" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="total" class="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>4</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
          <td>
            <select id="category">
              <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
              <option value="bsn">Business</option>
              <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
              <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
              <option value="tech">Technology</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="qty" class="qty_1" min="0" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="total" class="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>5</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="book-title" id="book-title"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="author" id="author"></td>
          <td>
            <select id="category">
              <option disabled selected>Please choose a category...</option>
              <option value="bsn">Business</option>
              <option value="fic">Fiction</option>
              <option value="math">Mathematics</option>
              <option value="tech">Technology</option>
            </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="number" name="price" class="price_1" min="0.00" value="0.00" step="0.01" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="qty" class="qty_1" min="0" value="0" /></td>
          <td><input type="number" name="total" class="total_1" min="0" value="0.00" step="0.01" readonly /></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
      <tfoot>
        <td colspan="5">
          <div style="text-align: right">
            <button onclick="calculate();">Calculate Grand Total Price</button>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div style="text-align: right;">
            <input type="number" name="grand_total" id="grand_total" value="0.00" readonly>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tfoot>
    </table>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```